# Is there an efficient way to find x given mod(ax;b)=c?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

It'll be the same thing as solving ax+by=c.

There's an algorithm to find gcd(x;y) with it you can solve that equation but it is very long for some pairs of numbers.

Of course a,b,c,x,y are all integers and a,b,c are known